# No such file or directory with TempDirectory()

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, temporary-files

I am creating two nested temp directories. One if to keep images copy, second is to write video which is simply playlist of images. This looks like that:

```
@app.route("/render/<filter_name>", methods=["POST"])
def render(filter_name: str):
    if request.method == "POST":
        f = request.files["file"]

        with TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
            in_dir = TemporaryDirectory(dir=tempdir)
            out_dir = TemporaryDirectory(dir=tempdir)

            image = Image.open(BytesIO(f.read()))

            image.save(in_dir.name + "/image.jpg", "JPEG")

            render_mp4(in_dir.name, out_dir.name, filter_name)

            filename = filter_name + ".mp4"
            fout = open(os.path.join(out_dir.name, filename), "rb")

            response = make_response(fout.read())
            response.headers.set("Content-Type", "video/mp4")
            response.headers.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment", filename=filename)
            return response
```

Unfortunately it seems that TemporartDirectory is closed faster that video is read because of:

```
[2020-05-26 18:17:45,152] ERROR in app: Exception on /render/dolly-zoom-in [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mat/miniconda3/envs/3DPhotoCreator/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/mat/miniconda3/envs/3DPhotoCreator/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/mat/miniconda3/envs/3DPhotoCreator/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/mat/miniconda3/envs/3DPhotoCreator/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/mat/miniconda3/envs/3DPhotoCreator/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/mat/miniconda3/envs/3DPhotoCreator/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "app.py", line 32, in render
    fout = open(os.path.join(out_dir.name, filename), "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmp6bmet26n/tmpne46ut4u/dolly-zoom-in.mp4'
```

Any tips on that? Is it fault of read binary aka "rb" in

```
open(os.path.join(out_dir.name, filename), "rb")
```

? Ant tips on this?

Thank you!

Comment: use `os.mkdirs` maybe

Comment: The error isn't caused by the temporary directory creation, it's when you try to open the file for reading. `filename` does not exist, so opening with mode `"rb"` fails. The `render_mp4` function seems not to be creating that file. Check the full path, and verify that the function works as you expect.